# AsteriskNOW and AGI Scripting

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

I'm currently trying to write my first AGI script in PHP to use on my AsteriskNOW server. All the tutorials i'm trying are not working, and i'm wondering if it may have to do with using AsteriskNOW instead of just Asterisk?

Also, where would I find the most up to date tutorials for a beginner AGI script writer?

Comment: you should provide expand on your question, add some snippets of code, what you think is causing the problem, and how you have tried to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There are nothing special in asterisknow. Please read manual carefully, most of manuals work ok. Before dooing AGI it is higly recomended do some dialplan application and read some solid book like "Asterisk the future of telephony".